# $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors in shiny 2022

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to do a shiny app for RFM analysis, but I don't know hot to solve the error of operator $. I'm already trying to convert vector in data frame, but this doesn't work and I don't know why.

This is my code

app_shiny:

```
# IMPORTAR DATA -----

directorio <- "D:/Cursos/Ciencia_Datos/Proyecto/Data/"
data <- file.path(directorio, "SEE_BaseDeDatos.xlsx")

data_original <- read.xlsx(xlsxFile = data, sheet = "Base_Facturacion")

data_ventas <- data_original %>%
  mutate( Total = str_replace(Total, pattern = ",", replacement = ".") ) %>% 
  mutate( Fecha_facturacion = as.Date(Fecha_facturacion, origin="1899-12-30")) %>% 
  mutate( Total = as.double(Total)) %>% #revisar no cambia a double
  filter( Total > 0) %>% 
  mutate( Tipo = trimws(Tipo))

analysis_date <- lubridate::as_date('2021-10-01')
df_RFM <- data_ventas %>% 
  group_by(Tipo) %>% 
  summarise(recency=as.numeric(analysis_date-max(Fecha_facturacion)),
            frequency =n_distinct(Factura),
            monetary= sum(Total))

# UI ----------------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Analisis RFM"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(
      numericInput(inputId = "selectorMontoMin", 
                   label = "Seleccione el monto minimo", 
                   value = df_RFM$monetary %>% min(), 
                   min = df_RFM$monetary %>% min(),
                   max = df_RFM$monetary %>% max()),
      
      numericInput(inputId = "selectorMontoMax", 
                   label = "Seleccione el monto maximo", 
                   value = df_RFM$monetary %>% max(), 
                   min = df_RFM$monetary %>% min(),
                   max = df_RFM$monetary %>% max()),
      
      selectInput(inputId = "selectorContinente", 
                  label = "Seleccione un continente", 
                  choices = gapminder %>% pull(continent) %>% unique(), 
                  selected = "Americas", 
      ),
      uiOutput(outputId = "selectorPais_out",
      ),
    ),
    mainPanel = mainPanel(
      h2(textOutput("titulo_grafica")),
      br(),
      plotOutput(outputId = "grafico"),
      hr(),
      h2("Información sobre los productos"),
      br(),
      DTOutput(outputId = "data_productos")
    )
  )
)

# Server ------------------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  df_filtrado <- reactive({
    
    valormin  <- input$selectorMontoMin
    valormax <- input$selectorMontoMax
    df1 <- df_RFM %>% filter( monetary <= valormax, monetary>valormin)
    
  })
  
  output$grafico <- renderPlot({
    
  source("prueba.R")
    nextWord <- df(max = input$selectorMontoMax,min = input$selectorMontoMin, plotData=TRUE)
   
    nextWord %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = segmentRFM, fill = segmentRFM)) + geom_bar() +
      labs(title = "Segmentacion de clientes",
           x = "Segmento",
           y = "Total Clientes") +coord_flip() + theme_minimal() + theme(legend.position='none')

    # df_filtrado() %>%
    #   ggplot(aes(x = monetary, y = frequency, color = recency, size = monetary))+
    #   geom_point()+
    #   labs(x = "PIB per capita", y = "Esperanza de vida", color = "País")+
    #   scale_x_log10(labels = dollar)+
    #   theme(legend.position = "bottom")

  })
  
  output$data_productos <- renderDT({
    
    df_filtrado() %>% 
      datatable(options = list(scrollX=T))
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba.R

```
df <- function(max=9000,min=0, plotData=TRUE){
  
  dataframe <- as.data.frame((df_RFM))
  str(dataframe)
  summary(dataframe)
  
  df_grafico1 <- df_RFM %>% filter( monetary <= max, monetary > min)
  df_grafico <- data.frame(df_grafico1)
  summary(df_grafico)
  print("HOLAAAAAAAAAAAA")
  str(df_grafico)
  summary(df_grafico)
  
  df_grafico <- df_grafico %>% add_column(R_Score = NA)
  df_grafico <- df_grafico %>% add_column(F_Score = NA)
  df_grafico <- df_grafico %>% add_column(M_Score = NA)
  
  df_grafico<-quantile(df_grafico$recency)
  
  #R_score
  df_grafico$R_Score[df_grafico$recency>qr1[4]]<-1
  df_grafico$R_Score[df_grafico$recency>qr1[3] & df_grafico$recency<=qr1[4] ]<-2
  df_grafico$R_Score[df_grafico$recency>qr1[2] & df_grafico$recency<=qr1[3] ]<-3
  df_grafico$R_Score[df_grafico$recency<=qr1[2]]<-4
  
  qf1<-quantile(df_grafico$frequency)
  #F_score
  df_grafico$F_Score[df_grafico$frequency<qf1[2]]<-1
  df_grafico$F_Score[df_grafico$frequency>=qf1[2] & df_grafico$frequency<qf1[3]]<-2
  df_grafico$F_Score[df_grafico$frequency>=qf1[3] & df_grafico$frequency<qf1[4] ]<-3
  df_grafico$F_Score[df_grafico$frequency>=qf1[4]]<-4
  
  qm1<-quantile(df_grafico$monetary)
  #M_score
  df_grafico$M_Score[df_grafico$monetary<= qm1[2]]<-1
  df_grafico$M_Score[df_grafico$monetary>=qm1[2] & df_grafico$monetary<qm1[3]]<-2
  df_grafico$M_Score[df_grafico$monetary>=qm1[3] & df_grafico$monetary<qm1[4] ]<-3
  df_grafico$M_Score[df_grafico$monetary>=qm1[4]]<-4
  
  #RFM_score
  df_grafico<- df_grafico %>% mutate(RFM_Score = 100*R_Score + 10*F_Score+M_Score)
  
  #Customer Segmentation
  #df1$segmentRFM<-NULL
  df_grafico <- df_grafico %>% add_column(segmentRFM = NA)
  top <- c(444)
  posicionados <- c(434,424,414,344,334,324,314,244,234,224,214)
  potenciales <- c(333,323,313,233,223,213,133,123,113,413)
  prometedor <- c(443,433,423,343,243,143,342,242,332,232,341,432,124,412,441,442)
  nopopular <- c(331,321,311,221,211,131,121,231,322,312,222,212,132,122,112,421,134,431,114)
  bajo <- c(111)
  
  df_grafico$segmentRFM[which(df_grafico$RFM_Score %in% top)] = "Top Ventas"
  df_grafico$segmentRFM[which(df_grafico$RFM_Score %in% posicionados)] = "Posicionados"
  df_grafico$segmentRFM[which(df_grafico$RFM_Score %in% potenciales)] = "Potencialmente posicionados"
  df_grafico$segmentRFM[which(df_grafico$RFM_Score %in% prometedor)] = "Prometedor"
  df_grafico$segmentRFM[which(df_grafico$RFM_Score %in% nopopular)] = "Poco popular"
  df_grafico$segmentRFM[which(df_grafico$RFM_Score %in% bajo)] = "Venta baja"
  
  df_grafico %>%  ggplot(data = df_grafico) + aes(x = segmentRFM, fill = segmentRFM) + geom_bar() +
    labs(title = "Segmentacion de clientes",
         x = "Segmento",
         y = "Total Clientes") +coord_flip() + theme_minimal() + theme(legend.position='none')
```

}

Comment: Hi, put this is in the original post, not as an answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).